# Allocation of Balls to Urns with Color-Dependent Probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I have $N$ balls of colors ranging from white to black, forming a discrete grayscale spectrum of $c$ different color bands. Initially, I have $N_i$ balls of the $i^{th}$ color band of the spectrum, such that $\sum_{i=1}^c N_i=N$. I need to distribute the $N$ balls into three urns: Urn A, Urn B, and Urn C. The capacity of Urn A is 90% of $N$ balls, while Urn B and Urn C can each accommodate 5% of $N$ balls. Additionally, there is a probability associated with each color band; let $P_i$ be the probability of placing a ball of the $i^{th}$ color band in the Urns.

In the grayscale spectrum, the probability of placing a ball in Urn C increases with the extent of black, while the probability of placing a ball in Urn A or Urn B increases with the extent of white. Balls with the greatest white are more likely in Urn C, whereas those with the most black are more likely in Urn A or Urn B.

How can I determine the distribution of balls in the three Urns, means what is $N_i$ at each Urn at the end of the experiment? Also, does this problem fall into a known distribution?

Comment: You have some precise statements $(90\% + 5\%+5\%=100\%)$ and some imprecise statements ("whitish balls are more likely to be placed in Urn C"), so there is not going to be a precise answer without knowing the details.  For example, you might have a  way of filling Urn C with some sort priority for whiter balls and then distribute the remaining balls between A and B randomly but in the ratio $18:1$.  Or some other mechanism.   Knowing how this is done make simulation easier and faster at suggesting an approximation to the distribution.

Comment: Thank you @Henry for the suggestion, I have clarified the question.

Comment: "For example, you might have a way of filling Urn C with some sort priority for whiter balls and then distribute the remaining balls between A and B randomly but in the ratio 18:1." - Henry. I want to fill all the Urns simultaneously. Starting with filling Urn C might give a different distribution than starting with filling Urn A or Urn B.

Comment: I cannot tell you how to fill the urns.  Perhaps you take each ball and distribute it between the urns in some way that takes account of the shade of the ball and the spaces remaining in the three urns (and possibly the shades of the balls still in your hand).  But I do no know any of this - if anybody does then you do.